# Data not shown in DataGridView with DataTable as DataSource

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to load a table in a DataGridView. For any reason the data is not displayed after the following code is executed through a button:

```
Private Sub btnLoadData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadData.Click
    BindDataGridView()
End Sub

Public Sub BindDataGridView()
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    With dt.Columns
        .Add("Id", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        .Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Add("Country", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    End With
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
    dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")
    FormTest.TestDatagridView.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

When I try the code above, the TestDatagridView is empty.

FormTest is a Form inside MainForm (main WinForm showed when when the application starts). It's displayed when the btnFormTest button is clicked:

```
Private Sub btnFormTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestForm.Click
    OpenChildForm(New FormTest)
End Sub

'Open the selected Form
Private Sub OpenChildForm(childForm As Form)
    'Open only form'
    If currentChildForm IsNot Nothing Then
        currentChildForm.Close()
    End If
    currentChildForm = childForm
    'end'
    childForm.TopLevel = False
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Controls.Add(childForm)
    Me.Tag = childForm
    childForm.BringToFront()
    childForm.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: You are displaying the data in the default instance of `FormTest`. Is it the default instance that you are looking at? I'm guessing not. If you don't, know please edit the question and provide the code that display your `FormTest` instance in the first place.

Comment: By the way, don't create `Type` objects that way. Use `GetType(String)` rather than `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` because then you can use a data type rather than a magic string and thus get compile-time checking. You'd only do it your way if the type name was being determined at run time and so you can't use a data type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for your fast reply. I edited the question.Please let me know if I can provide any other information that may help to clear up the problem.

Comment: Remove the `FormTest` from `FormTest.TestDatagridView.DataSource = dt`. Make it just `TestDatagridView.DataSource = dt`

Comment: @JQSOFT I found that it works perfectly when the code is inside the form and use the way you suggested. Thanks for that. But what I'm trying to do is load the DataGridView when the code is in a module (BindDataGridView()), making the call from the Form code (btnLoadData_Click).

Comment: I see. Use an instance of `FormTest` which is a type. For example, in your code you should use the `childForm` variable. `childForm.TestDatagridView.DataSource = dt` which is an instance.

Comment: That's not the same to `FormTest.TestDatagridView.DataSource = dt`?

Comment: How can I use childform variable in the module if it's declared in MainForm?

Comment: Pass it in a parameterized method buddy. `Public Sub BindDataGridView(chidForm As FormTest) ....` then use it `childForm.TestDatagridView.DataSource = dt`